# Showing unknown host exception in netBeans when sending mail using servlet

Tags: java, email, servlets, netbeans

there are my files:

index.html

```
<form action="servlet/SendMail">
To:<input type="text" name="to"/><br/>
Subject:<input type="text" name="subject"><br/>
Text:<textarea rows="10" cols="70" name="msg"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

SendMail.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SendMail extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String to=request.getParameter("to");

        String subject=request.getParameter("subject");

        String msg=request.getParameter("msg");

        Mailer.send(to, subject, msg);


        out.print("message has been sent successfully");
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Mailer.java

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.*;

import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Mailer {
public static void send(String to,String subject,String msg){

final String user="myid@gmail.com";

final String pass="*********";

Properties props = new Properties();

  props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");

        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", 
"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


Session session = Session.getInstance(props,

 new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

   return new PasswordAuthentication(user,pass);

   }
});

try {
 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

 message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));

 message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));

 message.setSubject(subject);

 message.setText(msg);

 Transport.send(message);

 System.out.println("Done");

 } catch (MessagingException e) {

    throw new RuntimeException(e);
 }

}
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting error? Any stacktrace? something like Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587; ??

Comment: Requires some debugging your code..

Comment: Have you internet connection while running..

Comment: yes i have internet connection @Satya.

Comment: @sheetal Mohan sharma i really have no idea where it is going wrong .

Comment: Post your error messages here..

Comment: How can we help unless we know the error or exception? if you want sample code then see this page www.javacirecep.com/internet/sending-email-using-gmail-smtp-in-java/

Comment: type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.